# FormBuilder group is deprecated

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-validation, angular2-formbuilder

I migrated my project to angular 11 and I noticed that the global validations that I added make `FormBuilder.group` deprecated with the message:

```
group is deprecated: This api is not typesafe and can result in issues with Closure Compiler renaming.
Use the `FormBuilder#group` overload with `AbstractControlOptions` instead.
```

so this is deprecated:

```
  ingredientForm = this.fb.group({
    ingredientType: ['', Validators.required],
    ingredientFlavor: [''],
    isMultiFlavor: [''],
    ingredientBrand: [''],
    ingredientName: [''],
    imageFile: ['']
  }, {validators: [ValidateThirdNumber.validate]});
```

and without the `validators` option it's not.

my `ValidateThirdNumber` validator:

```
class ValidateThirdNumber {
  static validate(control: AbstractControl): void {
      if (control) {
      const isMultiFlavor = control.get('isMultiFlavor')?.value;
      const ingredientFlavor = control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.value;
      const ingredientBrand = control.get('ingredientBrand')?.value;
      const ingredientName = control.get('ingredientName')?.value;
      if (isMultiFlavor && ingredientFlavor.trim().length === 0) {
        control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.setErrors({required_if: true});
      } else {
        control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.setErrors(null);
      }
      if (!ingredientFlavor && !ingredientBrand && !ingredientName) {
        control.get('ingredientName')?.setErrors({required_at_least: true});
        control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.setErrors({required_at_least: true});
        control.get('ingredientBrand')?.setErrors({required_at_least: true});
      } else {
        control.get('ingredientName')?.setErrors(null);
        control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.setErrors(null);
        control.get('ingredientBrand')?.setErrors(null);
      }
      if (ingredientBrand && ingredientName && ingredientName === ingredientBrand) {
        control.get('ingredientName')?.setErrors({not_the_same: true});
        control.get('ingredientBrand')?.setErrors({not_the_same: true});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how do I overload it with AbstractControlOptions ?

Comment: I think you can find the solution here in the section where the deprecation is explained: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder

Comment: @Ploppy  I read the docs before posting this question, unfortunately did not help much, no idea what to do

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Problem description

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group) we see two different lines with the `group()` function

> `group(controlsConfig: { [key: string]: any; }, options?: AbstractControlOptions): FormGroup`

**AND**

> <strike>`group(controlsConfig: { [key: string]: any; }, options: { [key: string]: any; }): FormGroup`</strike>

The 2nd definition is what is deprecated

The difference in this lines is `options?: AbstractControlOptions` and `options: { [key: string]: any; }`

To understand why angular is throwing this error we will now consider [`AbstractControlOptions`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlOptions#abstractcontroloptions)

```typescript
interface AbstractControlOptions {
  validators?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null
  asyncValidators?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null
  updateOn?: 'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'
}
```

We continue to breakdown the problem by noting that the difference between this structure and your structure is [`ValidatorFn[]`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn#validatorfn)

```typescript
interface ValidatorFn {
  (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null
}
```

Overally, the error is thrown in your case because your `Validator` function is expected to take a control and return `ValidationErrors | null`. In the line `validate(control: AbstractControl): void`, your code actually returns `void` but expected to return a `ValidationError | null`

## Solution

From the problem description, the solution is to simply modify the `ValidatorFn`

Ensure that your `ValidatorFn` returns a `ValidationError` or if no error returns `null`
From [ValidationErrors defination](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors)

```typescript
type ValidationErrors = {
    [key: string]: any;
};
```

You will need to return a key value pair object e.g `{required_if: true}`

We can change your code by adding return statements as expected

```typescript
class ValidateThirdNumber {
  static validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
      if (control) {
      const isMultiFlavor = control.get('isMultiFlavor')?.value;
      const ingredientFlavor = control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.value;
      const ingredientBrand = control.get('ingredientBrand')?.value;
      const ingredientName = control.get('ingredientName')?.value;
      if (isMultiFlavor && ingredientFlavor.trim().length === 0) {
        control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.setErrors({required_if: true});
        return ({required_if: true});
      } else {
        control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.setErrors(null);
      }
      if (!ingredientFlavor && !ingredientBrand && !ingredientName) {
        control.get('ingredientName')?.setErrors({required_at_least: true});
        control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.setErrors({required_at_least: true});
        control.get('ingredientBrand')?.setErrors({required_at_least: true});
        return ({required_at_least: true});
      } else {
        control.get('ingredientName')?.setErrors(null);
        control.get('ingredientFlavor')?.setErrors(null);
        control.get('ingredientBrand')?.setErrors(null);
      }
      if (ingredientBrand && ingredientName && ingredientName === ingredientBrand) {
        control.get('ingredientName')?.setErrors({not_the_same: true});
        control.get('ingredientBrand')?.setErrors({not_the_same: true});
        return ({not_the_same: true});
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: what if the custom validator has a complex logic that wouldn't be able to tell if setErrors block will run until runtime? e.g. something.forEach(ctl => {if xxx then setError, else ...}), what to expect to return in this scenario?

Answer (score 25):

Just change your last line:

```
}, {validators: [ValidateThirdNumber.validate]});
```

to

```
}, {validators: [ValidateThirdNumber.validate]} as AbstractControlOptions);
```

NOTE: Make sure the AbstractControlOptions is outside of the curly braces!

That's it.

Comment: Should the validators be with upper case or lower case "v"? I have followed you and put as lower case and the warning is gone.  Also, implemented the return along with setErrors as pointed out by OvenKelvin solution above.

Comment: It depends how you named your variable which you're returning from your custom validation class. It's case sensitive if you named it with lower or upper case.

Answer (score 3):

While [Owen Kelvin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65165250/10082415)'s answer is complete in explanation, I want to add a different answer pointing out the important points to have:

1. When specifying the validator function, only specify the function name (*i.e.*, without any parameters)
2. That validator function must accept one and only one parameter of type `AbstractControl`
3. The validator function must return `{key: value}` or `null`, but **not** just `null` all the time. Return `null` when there isn't an error to be displayed.

Here is an example of the form declared in the **RegisterPage.ts**:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      matchEmail: this.fb.group(
        {
          //email textfield
          email: new FormControl(
            '',
            Validators.compose([
              Validators.required,
              Validators.maxLength(64),
              Validators.email,
            ])
          ),
          //confirm email textfield
          confirmEmail: new FormControl(''),
        },
        { validators: this.matchEmail }
      ),
    });
  }
}
```

The validator function will create a new error type named `mismatch` and can be inserted in the **RegisterPage.ts** file:

```
matchEmail(group: AbstractControl) {
    let email: string = group.get('email').value;
    let confirmEmail: string = group.get('confirmEmail').value;
    if (email.localeCompare(confirmEmail) != 0) {
        //error
        group.get('confirmEmail')?.setErrors({ mismatch: true });
        return { mismatch: true };
    } else {
        //no error, return null (don't return { mismatch: false })
        return null;
    }
}
```

Your html can be something like this (you cannot access `confirmEmail` directly, it must be through the group it is a part of which is `matchEmail.confirmEmail`):

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('matchEmail.confirmEmail').hasError('mismatch')
    && (form.get('matchEmail.confirmEmail').dirty ||
    form.get('matchEmail.confirmEmail').touched)">
    <small>Confirmation email doesn't match</small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also receive same error, I make following changes.

- make sure that your validator function signature matches like this. (A function that receives a control and synchronously returns a map of validation errors if present, otherwise null.)

  - function Your_Function_Name(ObjectName: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null
    {
    }
- and you can change code in the form builder like this.

  - const **formOptions**: **AbstractControlOptions** = { validators: Your_Function_Name };
- and in the formbuilder object pass above formOptions object like this

  - this.formObject = this.formBuilder.group({
    fullName: ['', [Validators.required]]
    }, **formOptions**);

Comment: Hey, Can you please add a working code example??

Comment: @noahlubko, I have answered this with an example.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and my solution was this:

create a new variable like this:

```ts
const formOptions: AbstractControlOptions = {
   validators: your validator...,
   asyncValidators: your validators...
}
```

then insert this into your form builder group:

```ts
form: formGroup = this.fb.group({
  controls...
}, formOptions)
```

this removes the deprecated warning from my code.

hope it helps you.