# FormBuilder#group is deprecated in Jasmine test

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, angular-reactive-forms, deprecated

A linting error indicates:

> deprecation  group is deprecated: This API is not typesafe and can result in issues with Closure Compiler renaming. Use the `FormBuilder#group` overload with `AbstractControlOptions` instead.

I have read other question were the answer indacates the changes in formBuilder.group() however I only recieve the error in my spec.ts files for testing using Karma Jasmine.

I implement the test using `SpyObjects` and the implementation is as follows:

```
formBuilder = jasmine.createSpyObj<FormBuilder>('formBuilder', ['group']);
formBuilder.group.and.returnValue({ valueChanges: EMPTY, value: {} } as any);
```

The warning is shown for each line with `formBuilder.group`

Comment: group is deprecated. See [this][1] .


  [1]: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65155217/formbuilder-group-is-deprecated

Comment: I am aware of the deprication. However I am having a hard time spotting how to reimplement the `formBuilder.group` in the test to satisfy the linter.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65155217/formbuilder-group-is-deprecated?

Comment: Yes, I have. However as I'm not using ValidatorFn in my test implementation.